# percentage difference between two images in python using correlation coefficient

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I want to compare two image chunks such that if they are exactly the same, the result must be 1, and if they match 60 percent, the answer must be 0.6.

In Matlab, I can do this using `corr2` command, but in python I couldn't find a way. I have tried `numpy.corrcoef` but it returns a matrix and `scipy.signal.correlate2d` returns the same.

This is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filter import threshold_otsu
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import Image
import scipy
from PIL import Image as im
fname = 'testi.jpg'
image = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
arr = np.asarray(image)
global_thresh = threshold_otsu(arr)

global_otsu = arr >= global_thresh
global_otsu = np.invert(global_otsu).astype(int)
a1 = global_otsu[80:150,1350:1350+160]
fname1 = 'testi2.jpg'
image1 = Image.open(fname1).convert("L")
arr1 = np.asarray(image1)
global_thresh1 = threshold_otsu(arr1)

global_otsu1 = arr1 >= global_thresh1
global_otsu1 = np.invert(global_otsu1).astype(int)
a2 = global_otsu1[80:150,1350:1350+160]

co = scipy.signal.correlate2d(a1,a2)

plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(a1)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(a2)

plt.show()
```

and the result is:

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
..., 
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

These are the images that I want to compare:

[image: images that i want to compare]

Comment: Are the images going to be the same size?

Comment: yes they will be same size.

Comment: @EvilTak images will be of same size

Comment: Percentage difference as in how many pixels aren't same in the images?

Comment: @EvilTak yes as corr2 returns in matlab

Comment: Checking the [matlab docs of `corr2`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html), you can see what is calculated in matlab. The [docs of scipy.signal.correlate2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html) show what is calculated there, and it is something different. Use the formula from the matlab docs to implement `corr2` in python.

Comment: i have tried that also that gives some kind of warning because image is binary both chunks include zeros and in formula when it has to return the value due to 0/0 it make that value nan in resultant matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to compare pixel by pixel you can perform correlation on the flattened images, :

```
cm = np.corrcoef(a1.flat, a2.flat)
```

`cm`contains the symmetric correlation matrix where the off-diagonal element is the correlation coefficient. You get it by

```
r = cm[0, 1]
```

**Edit:**
There is a problem with using correlation for comparing images. If any of them is completely flat (all pixel the same value) the correlation is undefined.

If the images are binary you could instead simply calculate the percantage of equal pixels:

```
agreement = np.sum(a == b) / a.size
```

Comment: would this still work on a colored image? or just for greyscale or binary?

Comment: With this approach you would get something like the average correlation of all image channels. If that is how you define correlation of colored images it should work.